# using gSOAP to download a file via a WCF windows service

Tags: linux, wcf, web-services, gsoap

I have a Windows Communication Foundation web service that I need to access to
download a file from to my linux gsoap client.

The interface is as follows:

```
public interface IFileDownload
{
   [OperationContract]
   Stream GetUpdate(string updateName);
}
```

This function accepts a string (Unique name of file to download) and
returns a Stream which is the file to download.

This is already in use by other windows clients.

I need to build a linux gsoap client to call this.

I have built the calc example on the gsoap website and it works fine.
I have read that the functions to call must always return an int (error code)
and that the last parameter is actually the 'out' parameter.

What do I do in this case where the return type is Stream and not an int??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define a public property of type stream, and then have to tag it with **MessageContract**, and then manipulate the property from within the function.